# Have recent updates caused the iPad battery to not last as long?

Tags: ipad, battery

I'm noticing my iPad battery seems to be going down very rapidly, even when not in use. Has anyone else seen this behaviour and what would be the most common causes?

Comment: What OS version are you running? Have you checked for runaway backgrounded apps?

Comment: I've just gone and quit everything to make sure. Running latest public version - not a beta.

Comment: Is your 3G or Wi-Fi on? I've noticed on mine that the Wi-Fi antenna can look for signal if there isn't any and run down the battery that way.

Comment: I've done a hard reset which seems to have cleared up a number of issues including the Calendar app crashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try several things:

1. Close suspended apps. Double click home button, the screen items should raise and there is an extra row of apps appear at the bottom of the screen. Press and hold one of the apps that appear at the lower part of the screen (these are the apps that were suspended). When they start to shake/wiggle, press the red X on all of them to close them.
2. Check your email settings and make sure "push" is enabled and the "Fetch" is set to less frequent options
3. Your screen might be set to 100% brightness comparing with your previous usage settings
4. If you don't use any Bluetooth device with your iPad, you could turn the Bluetooth off by going to Settings > General > Bluetooth. That saves some power.
5. Try a hard-reset - full power off and on